# pybind11 multiple inheritance with custom holder type fails to cast to base types

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

#### Introduction:

This question is specific to interfacing C++ to python using the pybind11 library. The issue is concerning wrapping C++ classes which engage in multiple inheritance, and using user-defined holder types around them in python (instead of unique_ptr or shared_ptr).

#### Problem:

Suppose there are two pure abstract interface classes, **A** and **B**, which declare **foo()** and **bar()** pure abstract methods, respectively. Class **C** inherits from **A** and **B** publicly, and implements **foo()** and **bar()**. Class **MyHolder** is a custom, non-owning smart pointer, similar to a raw pointer but not implementing pointer arithmetic and other operators for safety.
Additionally, there are two functions which take **A** and **B** wrapped in **MyHolder**. The code works as expected in C++, but throw a runtime error when called from python.

I tried to reduce the code example to the smallest possible. As a consequence, the python example actually leaks memory. As this does not affect the reproducibility, I favoured less code against more correct code.

#### C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template< typename T >
class MyHolder
{
public:
    explicit MyHolder( T* ptr = nullptr ) : ptr_( ptr ) {}

    template< typename U > MyHolder( MyHolder< U > ptr ) : 
        ptr_( dynamic_cast< T* >( ptr.get() ) ) {}

    T* get() const { return ptr_; }
    T* operator-> () const { return ptr_; }

private:
    T* ptr_;
};

class A
{
public:
    virtual ~A() = default;
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() = default;
    virtual void bar() const = 0;
};

class C : public A, public B
{
public:
    C() = default;
    virtual ~C() = default;
    virtual void foo() const override
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void bar() const override
    {
        std::cout << "bar" << std::endl;
    }
};

void testA( MyHolder< A > ptr )
{
    ptr->foo();
}

void testB( MyHolder< B > ptr )
{
    ptr->bar();
}
```

#### pybind11 wrapping code

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include "Test.h"

PYBIND11_DECLARE_HOLDER_TYPE( T, MyHolder< T >, true );

PYBIND11_MODULE( test, m )
{
    pybind11::class_< A, MyHolder< A > >( m, "A" )
        .def( "foo", &A::foo );

    pybind11::class_< B, MyHolder< B > >( m, "B" )
        .def( "bar", &B::bar );

    pybind11::class_< C, MyHolder< C >, A, B >( m, "C" )
        .def( pybind11::init<>() );

    m.def( "testA", &testA );
    m.def( "testB", &testB );
}
```

#### C++ test code

```
#include "Test.h"

int main()
{
    auto uptr = std::unique_ptr< C >( new C() );
    auto c = MyHolder< C >( uptr.get() );
    testA( c );
    testB( c );
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
foo
bar

#### python test code

```
import test
c = test.C()
test.testA( c )
test.testB( c )
```

**Output:**
TypeError: testA(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: test.A) -> None

Invoked with: test.C object at 0x...

#### Additional cases checked

- It works if multiple inheritance is not involved (only inherit from **A** or **B**)
- It works if instead of **MyHolder**, **std::shared_ptr** is used
- In python, isinstance(c, A), isinstance(c, B) and a naturally isinstance(c, C) all returns **True** (which is strange), but still does not up-cast correctly

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on pybind11 issues page as well, and received an answer, which I will copy here for other users encountering the same issue.

**jagerman's answer:**

The issue here is that when multiple inheritance is involved we rely on a constructor compatible with std::shared_ptr's aliasing constructor (constructor (8) here), which lets us create a holder containing a recast pointer (i.e. an A *) that keeps the original C * alive (and, if it ends up being the last object, destroys the C * rather than the A *).

If you add:

```
MyHolder( const MyHolder &other, T* ptr ) : ptr_(ptr) {}
```

the example will work. (Your example holder doesn't do any actual memory management, of course; in reality it would need to support the sort of aliasing described above).